# Jquery $.ajax not working for the second time

Tags: jquery, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use a jquery ajax to call a vb method in code behind page on radio button change as below:

```js
$('body').on('change', 'input:radio', function() {
//$('input:radio').click(function () {
  var thisName = $(this).attr('name');
  var selected_Id = $('input[name=' + thisName + ']:checked').attr('id');

  valueIcLevelRadioButton = $("#" + selected_Id).val();

  var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("Default.aspx")%>'
  alert(pageUrl);
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: pageUrl + '/SetIcLevelRadioButton',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      args: valueIcLevelRadioButton,
      args1: thisName
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {

    },
  });
```

But, its working only for the first time and not working if I change or select the other radio buttons. Again, only after refreshing the page, its working.

Getting the below error if I try to select/change the other radio buttons second time.

[image]

Please let me know what is the issue here and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Aside from the issue, please remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice.

Comment: Is your `success` function actually empty or are you just omitted the code in there?
Despite that, your braces are not adding up

Comment: Success function is actually empty. yes, I just copied the part of the code.

Comment: The 500 error means that something is failing on the server side, have you tried debugging and stepping through your backend code for `SetIcLevelRadioButton`?

Comment: Breakpoint (SetIcLevelRadioButton) is not getting hit when I try to change the radiobutton second time.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the actual exception that was causing the issue. As pointed out by Ste Griffiths, it was due to server side exception. Used the below code to find the actual error.

```
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/RoutPrefix/Rout",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try using .live instead of .click event

Comment: 1) `live()` was deprecated almost 7 years ago and remove from the source over 5 years ago. You shouldn't be using it. 2) The OP is already using the delegated version of `on()` anyway, which is what `live()` used to do.

Comment: OK..then use .on event